# How i can make SQL query with multiple actions?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have an Items table and Images table. Single item have multiple images.
If you look at picture:

Image table post_id references id ( from items) . ( **One item post may have multiple images**)

How can i make an SQL Query which will First Delete all Images associated with a post and Then Delete Post. ( Basically i want from user to be able to delete his post).

```
Delete from images where post_id = 237;
Delete from items where id = 237;


ERROR:  update or delete on table "items" violates foreign key constraint "images_post_id_fkey" on table "images"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(237) is still referenced from table "images".
```

And i need to Delete ALL images(which are related to the post) before deleting Post because otherwise i will get an error. 
[image: Image Table]
[image: Item Table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
WITH d
AS
(
DELETE FROM images
            WHERE post_id = 240
            RETURNING post_id
)
DELETE FROM items
       WHERE id = (SELECT DISTINCT
                          post_id
                          FROM d);
```

But consider changing the foreign key constraint on `images` to `ON DELETE CASCADE`. Then the images of a post would get deleted automatically when the post is deleted.

And please don't post images of tables. Use `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT INTO` statements.